# Solve the functional equation $f(xf(y)+yf(x))=yf(x)+xf(y)$

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and such for any real numbers $x,y$ we have
 $$f(xf(y)+yf(x))=yf(x)+xf(y)$$
Find $f(x)$.

I have let $x=y=0$ have
$$f(0)=2f(0)\Longrightarrow f(0)=0$$

and I guess the solution is $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=0$, but I can't prove it.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ also satisfies the equation.

Comment: If you let $x=y=0$, you should get immediately $f(0)=0$ instead of $f(0)=2f(0)$.

Comment: This might help. Let $g(x)=f(x)/x$ and then put $y=1/x$

Comment: In the future, I'd kindly request that you put [tag:functional-equations] on these types of questions.

Comment: If we had $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ instead of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then $f$ could be any field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ of order $2$, and so there would be lots of solutions.

Comment: Where does the question come from?

Answer (score 10):

There are many such functions $f$, probably too many to classify in any useful way.

First, if $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$, say that $f$ is *good* if it satisfies the following property:

- For all $x,y\in A$, $xf(y)+yf(x)\in A$ and $f(xf(y)+yf(x))=xf(y)+yf(x)$.

The following lemma gives one way to construct many such functions.

**Lemma**: Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ with $0\in A$, let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be good, let $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$, and let $b\in\mathbb{R}$ be transcendental over the field generated by $A\cup f(A)\cup\{a\}$.  Then there exists $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $A\cup\{a\}\subseteq B$ and $|B|\leq |A|+\aleph_0$ and a good function $g:B\to\mathbb{R}$ which extends $f$ such that $g(a)=b$.

*Proof*:  Let $B_0=\{2ab\}\cup\{af(x)+bx:x\in A\}$.  Let $B_1$ be the closure of the set $B_0$ under the following operations:

- multiplication by $x+f(x)$ for any $x\in A$
- multiplication by $a+b$
- the binary operation $(x,y)\mapsto 2xy$.

Let $K$ be the subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $A\cup f(A)\cup\{a\}$; then clearly $B_1\subseteq K[b]$ (so in particular $|B_1|\leq |A|+\aleph_0$).  Moreover, $B_1$ contains no nonzero elements of $K$, since $B_0$ contains no nonzero elements of $K$ and $K[b]\setminus K$ is closed under all of these operations except when we multiply by $0$.

Now let $B=B_1\cup A\cup\{a\}$ and define $g:B\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in A$, $g(a)=b$, and $g(x)=x$ if $x\in B_1$.  Note that $g$ is well-defined, since $B_1\cap A=\{0\}$ and we must already have $f(0)=0$ since $f$ is good.

I claim that $g$ is good; to prove this, suppose $x,y\in B$.  If $x,y\in A$, then we are done since $f$ is good.  In all other cases, we will show that $xg(y)+yg(x)\in B_1$ and so $g(xg(y)+yg(x))=xg(y)+yg(x)$.  Here are all the cases (with cases which are equivalent to these by swapping $x$ and $y$ omitted):

- If $x\in A$ and $y=a$, then $xg(y)+yg(x)=xb+af(x)\in B_0$.
- If $x\in A$ and $y\in B_1$, then $xg(y)+yg(x)=xy+yf(x)=y(x+f(x))\in B_1$ since $B_1$ is closed under multiplication by $x+f(x)$.
- If $x=y=a$, then $xg(y)+yg(x)=2ab\in B_0$.
- If $x=a$ and $y\in B_1$, then $xg(y)+yg(x)=ay+yb=y(a+b)\in B_1$ since $B_1$ is closed under multiplication by $a+b$.
- If $x,y\in B_1$, then $xg(y)+yg(x)=xy+yx=2xy\in B_1$ since $B_1$ is closed under $(x,y)\mapsto 2xy$.

---

Now here's how you can use the lemma to construct good functions on all of $\mathbb{R}$.  Fix an enumeration $(r_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$ of the real numbers.  We construct our function $f$ by transfinite recursion as a limit of good partial functions $f_\alpha:A_\alpha\to\mathbb{R}$, starting with $A_0=\{0\}$ and $f_0:A_0\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f_0(0)=0$.  At limit steps, we just take unions.  At successor steps, we use the Lemma to extend $f_\alpha$ to a larger domain.  More precisely, let $a$ be the first number in our enumeration of the reals which is not in $A_\alpha$, and let $b$ be some real number that is transcendental over the field generated by $A_\alpha\cup f(A_\alpha)\cup\{a\}$.  (We can do this since by induction, $|A_\alpha|\leq |\alpha|+\aleph_0<\mathfrak{c}$.)  We then let $A_{\alpha+1}$ and $f_{\alpha+1}$ be $B$ and $g$ as given by the lemma.

In the end, this gives a function $f=\bigcup_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}} f_\alpha$ which is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and good, so it is a solution to your problem.  Moreover, by varying the choice of $b$ used in each successor step, we can get many different such functions ($2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ of them, though this takes a bit of work to prove).

Answer (score 1):

Most compactly written, part of the solution set is $$\{x\mapsto x\cdot\mathbb{1}_A(x):A\subseteq\mathbb{R},2\cdot A\cdot A\subseteq A,A\cdot(\mathbb{R}\backslash A)\subseteq A\}$$
where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is the indicator function on the set $A$. (Three such sets $A$ include $\varnothing$, $\{0\}$ (both giving $f(x)=0$), and $\mathbb{R}$ (which gives $f(x)=x$)) Now, consider the function $f(x)=x\cdot\mathbb{1}_A(x)$ where $A$ is such subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Take $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $x,y \in A$. Then, we have
$$\begin{split}
f(xf(y)+yf(x))&=f(xy+yx)\\&=f(\underbrace{2xy}_{\in A})\\&=2xy\\&=yx+xy\\&=yf(x)+xf(y).
\end{split}$$
Now, assume that $x,y \notin A$. Then, we have
$$\begin{split}
f(xf(y)+yf(x))&=f(0+0)\\&=f(0)\\&=0\\&=0+0\\&=y\underbrace{f(x)}_{0}+x
\underbrace{f(y)}_{0}.
\end{split}$$
Finally, assume that $x \in A$ and $y \notin A$ (the fourth case follows by symmetry). Then, we have
$$\begin{split}
f(xf(y)+yf(x))&=f(\underbrace{y}_{\notin A}\underbrace{f(x)}_{\in A})
\\&=f(\underbrace{yf(x)}_{\in A})\\&=yf(x)\\&=yf(x)+x\underbrace{f(y)}_{0}.
\end{split}$$
Now, let's attempt to show the converse. Suppose that a function $f$ satisfies $$f(xf(y)+yf(x))=yf(x)+xf(y)\text{ for all }x,y\in\mathbb{R}$$
and consider the set $$B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:f(x)=x\}.$$
Now, take $x,y \in B$. Then, we have
$$\begin{split}
f(2xy)&=f(x\underbrace{y}_{\in B}+y\underbrace{x}_{\in B})
\\&=f(xf(y)+yf(x))\\&=xf(y)+yf(x)\\&=xy+yx\\&=2xy
\end{split}$$
so $2xy\in B$ as well. Now, suppose that $x \in B$ *but* $y \notin B$. I would not have any idea how to prove that $xy \in B$ as well. The only thing I know is that taking $x=y=1/2$ leads to $f(f(1/2))=f(1/2)$ so $f(1/2) \in B$ as well...

Comment: But $\mathbb R$ is a field, so only ideals in it are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb R$. However, your solution requires only $2 \cdot A \cdot A \subseteq A$ and $A \cdot (\mathbb R \setminus A) \subseteq A$, so maybe there are some non-trivial sets with this property...

Comment: The empty set satisfies the requirements you set for $A\subset\Bbb{R}$, so there is no need to include the zero map in the set of solutions separately.

Comment: I already posted the spin-off, you can find it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233500/can-one-characterize-the-set-of-all-a-subseteq-mathbbr-satisfying-2-cdot-a).

Comment: @Servaes Strangely enough, $A=\varnothing$ and $A=\{0\}$ give the same function.

Comment: @mihaild As you can read in the answer, I managed to prove that the first requirement you posed is necessary but I didn't manage to prove the second. Also, _if_ it turns out that the solution set as I described in the answer is the full solution set, we will still have problems characterizing it.

Comment: I think there are no non-trivial solutions of this form (see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3233551/659499) to your question).  The general requirement, if $B_\alpha = \{x | f(x) = \alpha x\}$ is $B_\alpha \cdot B_\beta \cdot (\alpha + \beta) \subseteq A$, and your conditions are necessary if $f$ is always $x$ or $0$. I don't know how to handle case when $f(x) / x$ is different from $0$ and $1$.

Comment: That sounds profound, I would agree on that. Maybe someone will find a solution to that particular case.